# datagrid freezing before bind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a simple ASP.net page with an old datagrid. When a user clicks a button, a select statement runs and binds the data to the grid. The problem is after the page loads, the screen just hangs. There is only 1 record in the table.

ASP PAGE

```
<asp:Button ID="buttonclick" OnClick="clickit" runat="server" Text="GO" /> 

<asp:DataGrid ID="mygrid"  runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:DataGrid>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
  public void clickit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string sql = "SELECT a from table1";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        SqlDataAdapter adap= new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        connection.Open();
        adap.Fill(table); //page reloads here, but hangs
        mygrid.DataSource = table;
       connection.Close();
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried the page on different browsers and if not do you experience the same behaviour?

Comment: can you connect & fill from your home computer?

Comment: This shouldn't matter but shouldn't you call mygrid.DataBind()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have refactored your code , now it should work.

```
public void clickit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call the function
    this.bindGrid();
}

 //function to populate the datagrid with the data from the datasource
   private void bindGrid()
   {
    string sql = "SELECT a from table1";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    SqlDataAdapter adap= new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    connection.Open();
    adap.Fill(table); //page reloads here, but hangs
    mygrid.DataSource = table;
    //bind the control with the data in the datasource
    mygrid.DataBind();
   connection.Close();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to call mygrid.DataBind() after assigning the DataSource? It might not be hanging. It's probably just not displaying the grid with the data bind.